# Get IP From Mac Address With Nmap Command on Linux?

Tags: linux, awk, nmap

Given the following Nmap output, how can I extract the IP address which matches a particular MAC address?

```
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.2
Host is up (0.0011s latency).
MAC Address: 00:02:CF:E2:52:4E (ZyGate Communications)
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.9
Host is up (0.015s latency).
MAC Address: 1C:18:4A:08:88:48 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.35
Host is up (0.019s latency).
MAC Address: B8:B4:2E:F9:2B:B1 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.40
Host is up (0.00036s latency).
MAC Address: 00:25:11:2C:F6:9C (Elitegroup Computer System )
```

I would like a pipeline something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
nmap -sP 10.0.0.0-255 | grep 00:25:11 | awk '{print IP ADDRESS}'
```

Comment: Post expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this may help;

```
nmap -sP....|awk -v mac="00:25:11" '/report for/{ip=$5}$0~mac{print ip}'
```

You just change the `mac="00:25:11"` part to do different MAC filtering.

If you test this line on your example, it output:

```
10.0.0.40
```

Comment: Empty IP is not allowed, you'll get "Failed to resolve "....". Scantype . not supported"

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing - what's the question/problem really?!

In general, you can't get or resolve IP from MAC or vice versa. You can try to build up a database of recently found IP+MAC matches, but this pair is independent. MAC spoofing and moving laptops/smartphones can be helpful to imagine. Device has MAC, but ISP provides IP. There's no way to resolve one from the other. You get this info usualy inside TCP/IP packets.

Comment: I know. I am talking about local network.

Comment: supposed you only use simple ping, and you have root permissions you can try: `sudo nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24 | grep -B 2 E1:08:CC | grep report | cut -d ' ' -f 5`. This will work only in simple ping, for other scans MAC address may be some lines more further down

Comment: MAC to IP matching on local networks is handled using ARP (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc826). You can use the arp command to examine the local arp cache.